# Move and expand set of points to fill HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a set of coordinates formatted like so:

```
[{"x": 336.3333320617676, "y": 802.8020935058594}, {"x": 758.3333320617676, "y": 783.8020935058594}, ...]
```

And I need to find a way to take these points and change them into a set that will take a canvas of an arbitrary size and fill it as much as possible with this shape whilst making sure it all remains visible and is centred (i.e. take a triangle half the height of the canvas, double its size, and centre it on the canvas.

I would post some code of previous attempts, but after several days of trying, I haven't gotten even close. This is probably very simple, but my maths is terrible.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: those previous attempts are important to share, if only to let everyone know you're trying. Its a thing...

Comment: Well, if I'm honest, what I'm actually trying to say is that I deleted them out of frustration. They involved a lot of trying to find the ratio of the width of the shape as a bounding box and multiplying the coords by that ratio and then adding a width/height modifier of the width of the canvas divided by 2 and the width of the bounding box divided by 2, adjusting for the multiplication, but got nowhere.